# Cannot start another activity

Tags: android-activity, android

I followed the full instructions on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html multiple times and have been unable to start an activity. The app basically has a text field and send button. When I enter text in the text field and hit the send button, another activity should be started. However, with my current code, hitting the send button does nothing.

---

MySecondApp/src/MainActivity.java

---

```
package com.example.mysecondapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.mysecondapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

---

MySecondApp/src/DisplayMessageActivity.java

---

```
package com.example.mysecondapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

MySecondApp/res/layout/activity_main.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />
            android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

MySecondApp/res/layout/activity_display_message.xml

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

MySecondApp/res/values/strings.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Safe\'s First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>
```

---

MySecondApp/AndroidManifest.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mysecondapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mysecondapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mysecondapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.mysecondapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.mysecondapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: If you look closely to your manifest, you'll notice your `DisplayMessageActivity` is lacking an `IntentFilter` declaration.

Comment: @tolgap He only needs to include an IntentFilter within his manifest for activities that need it, which is why there is an IntentFilter in his main activity, declaring it his main. His actual error lies in the button xml in MySecondApp/res/layout/activity_main.xml as I noted below

Comment: @ChrisM I actually missed that as that fell outside the StackExchange app's view.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the xml for your first activity. You have two terminating characters in the Button. Remove the /> after your android:text line.

Comment: Your edit on his post was incorrect. It wasn't a redundant block. The second block of xml code was showing to take away the `android:onClick` property with his *second* way of using the code.

Answer (score 1):

Change you xml:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />
            android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

to:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send" 
            android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

And also, I think you should reference your button in the onCreate method.

You can also try to change your code to:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.mysecondapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourid);

        yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, YourSecondActivity.class);
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
                String message = editText.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And Change your xml from:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />
            android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

To:

```
 <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/button_send" 
                />
```

Comment: Why do you need : public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.mysecondapp.MESSAGE";

and,

String message = editText.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

? if your intention is just to start a new activity

Comment: Referencing the button in src and adding the onclicklistener is not needed as he is already declaring the onclick action within his xml.

Comment: I understand..but if he just wants to start another activity on click of button, why to use extra step?

Comment: The reason for those lines is to access the value from his first activity in his second activity.

And how is declaring in xml rather than src an extra step?

Comment: @ChrisM He showed him two ways to do it (use a button listener). It's a good answer.

Comment: I am not saying that the method is wrong.. but, anyways if he wants to  pass the message to a diff activity, setting an onClickListerner wouldn't harm.. and its not like I am asking him to the same method I posted here, I also gave an alternative to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

See how the last line is black? That's because you ended the button tag *twice* with `/>`

So take the closing tag away on the second last line: `android:text="@string/button_send"`

and your code would be:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When locating the onClick property and select sendMessage [MainActivity] from the drop-down list, at .xml file: android:onClick="sendMessage (MainActivity)".
Delete "(MainActivity)":
So, at .xml file: android:onClick="sendMessage" 
And run the app again!

Comment: Can you rephrase your answer, it's hard to follow.